# Converting NVARCHAR to INT datatype in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion, aggregate-functions

I am getting this error message:-

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '50AB' to data type int

when running the below query in SQL Server 2008:

```
select 
    max(cast(substring(c.customername, 12, 4) as integer)) 
from customers c
```

Please help me with the conversion type which I can use to fix this issue. I have already tried using `Convert` and I still have the same issue.

Comment: That's because you can't convert letters into numbers like this. You'll have to either remove the letters or convert them to numbers somehow.

Comment: Yeah, but looks like in sql server 2012 we can use try_cast to get rid of it..do we have something similay for sql server 2008?

Comment: **No**- `TRY_CAST` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** - if you need it, you have to upgrade to 2012 (or newer)

Comment: try_cast would fail with a text string and return a NULL anyway. You need to remove the text values if you wish to convert to a number. Think about it, what number is equivalent to 'A'? How is SQL Server going to know that?

Comment: @RichBenner maybe NULL is OP's goal.   The goal isn't stated clearly in the question.   What would a successful "fix" look like?   We don't know.

Comment: Null is what we are expecting out of that query.

Comment: @TabAlleman that's a fair point. I've posted an answer that returns null when it's not convertible.

Comment: Any other work around to get Null instead of an error message in this scenario.

Comment: @ManishAgarwal i gave you a way to do this below. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another logic that will convert the column to `INT` if it's possible, similar to `TRY_CONVERT` in 2012 onward.

The case condition checks to see when your column **IS NOT LIKE** any non-digit. It's a short way of checking if your column **IS LIKE** any character or special character. If there is anything other than a digit in that column, the conversion isn't done. If it's only digits (which is what we need for an `INT` conversion) then the conversion is done.

```
SELECT
    IdField
    ,DataField
    ,CASE WHEN DataField NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CONVERT(int, DataField) END New_Column
FROM #SampleData
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working on SQL Server 2008..Will this work in case my users are connected via Oracle db as well?

Comment: Glad it worked for you @ManishAgarwal. I'm not well versed on ORACLE syntax I'm afraid but logically it will.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a `NULL` value when it cannot be converted you could use a `CASE` with `ISNUMERIC`. Something like this;

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData (IdField int, DataField nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO #SampleData (IdField, DataField)
VALUES
(1,'50AB')
,(2,'1234')
```

Query

```
SELECT
    IdField
    ,DataField
    ,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(DataField) = 1 THEN CONVERT(int, DataField) END New_Column
FROM #SampleData
```

Result

```
IdField DataField   New_Column
1       50AB        NULL
2       1234        1234
```

Comment: Just want to make a note that this isn't bullet proof, and there really isn't a bullet proof method prior to 2012 but if the value was something like '1e4' or '$' or an array of other options which would equate to `ISNUMERIC = 1` the convert will fail. `select case when ISNUMERIC('1e4') = 1 then convert (int,'1e4') end`

Comment: @scsimon thats correct, this does not work in all cases, any other work around which could cater to the scenario?

Comment: @ManishAgarwal is it ONLY alpha numeric or is there special characters as well?

Comment: Its only alphanumeric.